# Codeigniter submit function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

on my http://localhost/qconsolidated/login_controller/login this error appears:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.

I always get this error everytime i click the submit button on my form. I have checked my it back and forth for 2 days now, and still could't get it right. please help me. Here are the codes that I made:

login_controller.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('login_view');
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }

    public function login(){
            echo "<script> alert('Working!'); </script>";   
    }
```

login_view.php

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-login" method="post" action="/login_controller/login">

        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/img/q_logo.png">

        <label class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your action url.

```
<form class="form-login" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>/login_controller/login">
```

Answer (score 0):

change form action.Use something like this

```
<form class="form-login" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('login_controller/login');?>">
```

you can also achieve this by using form_open('login_controller/login');

Answer (score 0):

Try like this used **base_url**

```
<form class="form-login" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url("login_controller/login");">
```